# Java elasticsearch client always null

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've recently made the switch from elasticsearch 1.7 to 2.0 and I noticed the way you setup the client has changed. I went through the documentation and for some reason the client is always null. I was wondering if I have set it up correctly.

Here is my code:

```
    Client client = null;

    try {
        client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger.log(e);
    } finally {
        client.close();
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Logger.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an exception? Your syntax is as it should be

Comment: I am receiving this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;`

Comment: this is completely guava related and pertains to a problem with several guava versions in the same time. I suggest you to do a clean compile. If this is a war file delete the folder of project inside webapps and redeploy.

nothing to do with ES

Comment: I've fixed the issue, it seemed to be a dependency issue, now I'm facing this issue: `Method threw 'java.lang.StackOverflowError' exception. Cannot evaluate org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.toString()`

Comment: @DanielBuckle Hi, were you able to solve the `StackOverflowError` issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As noted in the comments, but a little bit more in detail: Elasticsearch 2.0 uses Guava 18.0 (see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7593). So to fix errors like `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concu‌rrent/Executor;`, make sure to use Guava 18.0 as dependency and not other versions.

Comment: Have tried using Guava 20.0 with elasticsearch 2.4.1 and it works! But its quite strange that Guava 15.0 seem to be working with the ES 2.3.5. IMHO, Its still a good idea to use Guava 18.0 or higher while upgrading to ES 2.0 or higher.