# Error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;

Tags: scala, api, elasticsearch, concurrency

I get error, just like the title. I'm already research, and found some similar, but its not working on me.

- [NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor conflits on Elastic Search jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157642/nosuchmethoderror-com-google-common-util-concurrent-moreexecutors-directexecuto)
- [Java elasticsearch client always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33544863/java-elasticsearch-client-always-null)
- https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/7593
- [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError during Elastic search start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452023/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-during-elastic-search-start)
- https://discuss.elastic.co/t/transportclient-in-2-1-x/38818/6

I'm using Scala as programming language to create API, and Elasticsearch as database.

here is my code **build.sbt**

```
name := "LearningByDoing"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"
resolvers += "spray nightlies repo" at "http://nightlies.spray.io"

libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-json_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-can_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-client_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-testkit_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-routing_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-http_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-httpx_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-util_2.10" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-can_2.10" % "1.3.2"

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.12"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.sksamuel.elastic4s" % "elastic4s-streams_2.10" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-mapper-attachments" % "2.3.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.10" % "2.3.1"
```

Here is my code **plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0-M4") 
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-multi-jvm" % "0.3.9")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "0.8.0")
```

at terminal, I was written **sbt clean compile test update package** and everything works normal. but when I hit the API is always come error like that.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some wrong guava version, just like the [firs link](http://NoSuchMethodError:%20com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor%20conflits%20on%20Elastic%20Search%20jar) you mentioned, may be with [this](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) sbt plugin you can see the dependency tree and figured it out some messing dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the TCP client for Elasticsearch since 5.0 uses Netty 4.1, which is incompatible with Spray which uses Netty 4. There is no workaround other than waiting for Spray to upgrade or switching to an elasticsearch HTTP client.